# Как можно сделать css градиент как на изображении?

Tags: css, css3

Всем привет! Просьба подсказать как можно сделать css градиент в точности как на прилагаемом изображении? [image: gradient]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div{
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(250,245,241,1) 0%,rgba(254,253,251,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```